# mysqli_fetch_array not getting the info

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hey so am making a sign up page everything is working but the mysqli_fetch_array is not getting the info from the database

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('$fname','$lname','$email','".md5(md5($email).$password)."','$company_name','','','','','') ";
$suq = mysqli_query($link , $query);
$getinf = mysqli_fetch_array($suq);

if($suq){

$_SESSION['email'] = $getinf['email'] ;
$_SESSION['id'] = $getinf['id'] ;
$userID = $_SESSION['id'] ; 
$query2 = "UPDATE `users` SET emailcode='$emailCode' 
WHERE id='$userID'";
mysqli_query($link , $query2);
 //********
 $to = $getinf['email'] ;
 $from = array("FROM: noreply@sadeqrasheed.com","Content-type: text/html");

$body = "email code =$emailCode <br/> ";
 $subject = "Verify Email";

 if(mail($to , $subject, $body , implode("\r\n",$from) )){

    }       
 header("Location: verify.php");
```

in the verify.php i echo the email session but it's empty which means the fetch array didn't get the info
now as i said everything is working the query is submitting the info to the DB bit the fetch array is not getting any info any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `INSERT`ing into the database, this doesn't return a result set. You would need to `SELECT` the row you have just inputted if you wanted to get the data back.

Example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('$fname','$lname','$email','".md5(md5($email).$password)."','$company_name','','','','','') ";
$suq = mysqli_query($link , $query);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";
$query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$getinf = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

You may also want to research object orientated mysqli, as it is much cleaner to read.

Comment: It might be a good idea not to salt the password with the users email, as this would mean changing their password is mandatory when editing their password... as well as perhaps been less secure.

Comment: thanks for the tip well i learned this from the complete web developer -  Build 14 sites and he done that 
but i will change it thank you so much

Comment: @SadeqRasheed If I helped be sure to accept (the tick button) my answer.

Comment: i don't forget that 
but the site didn't let me accept the answer for the past 10 minutes